# How to wait for all threads created within a method

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, starcounter

In c#, I have to ensure that a certain block of code in a handler will only be executed after several threads finish. Those threads are invoked from a method that is called in the same handler, immediately before the aforementioned block of code. The syntax used is related with the DBMS that I am using, namely Starcounter.

```
Handle.GET("/path/to/HandlerStartTests", () =>
{
    // some code

    startMethod();

    // some code that relies on what happens within startMethod
}

public static void startMethod()
{
    QueryResultRows<PO> pos = Db.SQL<PO>("SELECT po FROM PO po");
    foreach (var po in pos)
    {
        DbSession dbSession = new DbSession();
        dbSession.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            // Do some stuff in the Starcounter database
        });
    }
}
```

This is for unit testing purposes, so I can't do any changes in the `startMethod`. Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Does dbSession.RunAsync return a Task?

Comment: I would call dbSession.RunSync wrapped in Task.Run, collect those Tasks and wait for them with Task.WaitAll

Comment: I'd suggest looking into thread parallelism : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Look about join() https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Julien698 I don't think join is useful here. The reason why is explained in the comments to the first reply I had

Comment: @rsy If the code you want to run in the background accesses Starcounter objects, it must be run on a Starcounter thread (i.e., not with `Task.Run()`)

Comment: @MartinTörnwall sorry for the delay, just arrived from holidays. As I state above, inside the startMethod I invoke the following construct: 

DbSession dbSession = new DbSession();
dbSession.RunAsync(() => {

}

Not with Task.Run, so I suppose it is run in a starcounter thread!? What I want to do is to wait for these threads, which are invoked from inside the startMethod() code, to be waited in the handler code, which invokes this method. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @rsy You are correct; my comment was in reference to what I mistook for a suggestion to do Starcounter object access on a thread pool thread. The accepted answer looks like a reasonable approach, I think. But I see no way of achieving what you're asking for without modifying `startMethod` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startMethod is fire and forget, because async Tasks are'nt collected in DbSession.RunAsync(). Without modifying this method there is no reference to the started Task's to wait for.

If this method could be modified one could wrap a sync call DbSession.Sync() if such is defined in a Task and wait for those tasks.

```
QueryResultRows<PO> pos = Db.SQL<PO>("SELECT po FROM PO po");
List<Task>tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var po in pos)
{
    DbSession dbSession = new DbSession();
    var task = Task.Run(()=>
    dbSession.RunSync(() =>
    {
        // Do some stuff in the Starcounter database
    }));
    tasks.Add(Task);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: I can't make any modifications in the startMethod(). As I have written in the question, after the code, this is for unit testing purposes, and that's precisely the method I am supposed to test.

Comment: The startMethod is fire and forget, if it can't be altered: there is just nothing to wait for.

Comment: I have been discussing this in the office, and seems you are right @Mikey. So, feel free to edit your answer, stating also this limitation you've mentioned, which is related to my question, and I will gladly mark it as solved tomorrow, after going through the problem one more time :)